# Compiling to XML doc with csc -- Errors

Tags: c#-3.0

When trying to convert comments to a xml doc, such as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve request type
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Collection</returns>
```

I get many errors.
(The names have been changed to protect the innocent.)

It complains about Abba.Domain, Abba.Service, and Abba.Style.Manager

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Abba.Domain;
using Abba.Service;
using Abba.Style.Manager;
```

Example errors:

```
c:\Users\waldo\Documents\App_Test\App_Code\Section_A\Abba.cs(6,11): error CS0234
4: The type or namespace name 'Domain' does not exist in the namespace 'ABA'
        (are you missing an assembly reference?)

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NAME' could not be found
```

What am I missing?
 (Besides more knowledge of C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Abba.Domain, Abba.Service and Abba.Style.Manager is located in additional .cs file, make sure you add them to the csc input.

something like:

```
csc /out:abba.dll /target:library /doc:abba.xml abba.domain.cs abba.service.cs abba.style.manager.cs abba.cs
```

if you have the rest of the .cs file in a directory you can also use /recurse:lib/*.cs

Similarly, if you Abba.* is already compiled in a dll, you might want to add /reference option.

Once all the references are resolved, you should be okay.